# Convert complex NumPy array into (n, 2)-array of real and imaginary parts

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a complex-valued NumPy array that I'd like to convert into a contiguous NumPy array with real and imaginary parts separate.

This

```
import numpy

u = numpy.array([
    1.0 + 2.0j,
    2.0 + 4.0j,
    3.0 + 6.0j,
    4.0 + 8.0j
    ])

u2 = numpy.ascontiguousarray(numpy.vstack((u.real, u.imag)).T)
```

does the trick, but transposing, vstacking, *and* converting to a contiguous array is probably a step or two too much.

Is there a native NumPy function that does this for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the alternatives are `native` or save on reshape, transposes etc.

For example internally `column_stack` converts its inputs to 2d 'column' arrays.  Effectively it is doing

```
In [1171]: np.concatenate((np.array(u.real,ndmin=2).T,np.array(u.imag,ndmin=2).T),axis=1)
Out[1171]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  8.]])
```

`vstack` passes its inputs through `atleast_2d(m)`, making sure each is a 1 row 2d array.  `np.dstack` uses `atleast_3d(m)`.

A new function is `np.stack`

```
In [1174]: np.stack((u.real,u.imag),-1)
Out[1174]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  8.]])
```

It uses `None` indexing to correct dimensions for concatenation; effectively:

```
np.concatenate((u.real[:,None],u.imag[:,None]),axis=1)
```

All end up using `np.concatenate`; it and `np.array` are the only compiled joining functions.

Another trick is to use `view`

```
In [1179]: u.view('(2,)float')
Out[1179]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  8.]])
```

The complex values are saved as 2 adjacent floats.  So the same databuffer can be viewed as pure floats, or with this view as a 2d array of floats. In contrast to the `concatenate` functions, there's no copying here.

Another test on the alternatives is to ask what happens when `u` is 2d or higher?

Comment: Can the same be done to save copying with a N x M array of complex? To make N x M x 2 of float64?

Answer (score 13):

I've compared the suggested solutions using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot). For large vector sizes, the constant-time view

```py
u.view("(2,)float")
```

is indeed the fastest variant. For smaller `n`,

```py
numpy.column_stack([u.real, u.imag])
```

is probably the best (cleanest, fastest) option.

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy
import perfplot


def setup(n):
    return numpy.random.rand(n) + 1j * numpy.random.rand(n)


def column_stack(u):
    return numpy.column_stack([u.real, u.imag])


def dstack(u):
    return numpy.dstack((u.real, u.imag))[0]


def concatenate(u):
    return numpy.concatenate(
        (numpy.array(u.real, ndmin=2).T, numpy.array(u.imag, ndmin=2).T), axis=1
    )


def stack(u):
    return numpy.stack((u.real, u.imag), -1)


def view(u):
    return u.view("(2,)float")


perfplot.save(
    "out.png",
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[column_stack, dstack, concatenate, stack, view],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(22)],
)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and stack the two 1-D arrays as columns to make a single 2D array.

```
In [9]: np.column_stack((u.real,u.imag))
Out[9]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  8.]])
```

Comment: I just checked this out :) it avoids the ugly indexing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dstack`:

```
np.dstack((u.real, u.imag))[0]
#Out[210]:
#array([[ 1.,  2.],
#       [ 2.,  4.],
#       [ 3.,  6.],
#       [ 4.,  8.]])
```